# MapView start position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good afternoon,

When i'm starting my application, the mapview is showed like you can see in the follow picture :

[image]

but i would like to start the mapview with some zoom in some point, something similar to this :

[image]

Which method i need to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a zoom level to the map controller:

```
mapView.getController().setZoom(17); // an int that suits you
```

Read more about zoom levels here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Zoomlevels

To set center you can use:

```
 mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude));
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, how can i determine that int?

EDIT : I meant, i want to change the geoPos that is being zoomed. For example, now is somewhere in America and i want in Egypt.

Comment: Check this out: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Zoomlevels I usually try in google maps first :)

Comment: You can use:  mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude));

Answer (score 0):

set -

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mapView.getController().setZoom(17); // an int that suits you
 mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude));
```

This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

for displaying egypt use it-

```
  String coordinates[] = {"18.352566007", "73.78921587"};//here you can set geopoints of egypt
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));//p is GeoPoint

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mapView.invalidate();
```